# Tkinter file dialog box, passes file path and runs rest of script, converting to .app

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, tkinter, pyinstaller

I've build a script which reads a log (text) file and performs certain formatting, then writes a html file and opens it automatically. Everything works fine when I tell it which path to look for the log file specifically. I'm not great with GUI in Python, so I found some code for Tkinter and edited it a little to do what I needed. So now, the user can select the file and then it will run the rest of the script.

It works when I run the script in terminal. This launches a file dialog box, once the file is selected it automatically runs the script and opens the html file with the formatted text.

I've now tried making this into a .app using PyInstaller

I followed the instructions and used 
`pyinstaller --onedir --windowed beta1.py`

this generated a .app file in the dist folder but when I double click it, it doesn't do anything, there is no attempt to open the file.

I'm not sure what I've done wrong here. I've posted my code below:

```
import webbrowser 
import os
import re
import tkinter
from tkinter import filedialog
import os

root = tkinter.Tk()
file = filedialog.askopenfile(parent=root,mode='rb',title='Choose a file')
if file != None:
    data = file.read()
    file.close()

if file:
    filepath = file.name


root.quit()
infile = filepath


fixed_div = """
<style>#fixed_div {
    background: #555;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    min-height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 60px;
    font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif;
}

#logtext {
    padding: 100px 0px 0px;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    line-height: 1.5;

}

a, u {
    text-decoration: none;
}

#fixed_div a:link { color: white; }
#fixed_div a:visited { color: white; }
#fixed_div a:hover { color: #FF715B; }
#fixed_div a:active { color: #F3E476; }


a.anchor {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: -250px;
    visibility: hidden;
}</style><br>"""




with open(infile) as f:
    f = f.read()
    error_occurances = f.count("ERROR:")
    fail_occurances = f.count("FAIL:")

with open(infile, 'r') as IN, open('output.html', 'w') as OUT:
    OUT.write(fixed_div)
    OUT.write('<head><meta charset="UTF-8"></head>')
    OUT.write('<body>')
    OUT.write('<div id="fixed_div">')
    OUT.write('<div id="title"><font color="white"><font size="5"><strong><a href="#">&#xF8FF LOG READER</a></strong></font></font></div>')
    for x in range(error_occurances):
        error_links = "ERROR " + str(x)
        OUT.write('<a href=' + '"' + '#' + error_links + '"' '>' + error_links + "\t" + '&#9702;' + '</a>' + "\t")


    OUT.write('</div>')
    OUT.write("<pre id='logtext'>")
    x = 0
    for line in IN:
        if "ERROR" in line:
            error_links = "ERROR " + str(x)
            x+=1
            f = '<a class="anchor" id=' + '"' + error_links + '"' '></a><span style="background-color: #ff0000; color: #ffffff;">' + line + '</span>'
            OUT.write(f + '\n')
        elif "FAIL:" in line:
            OUT.write(line.replace('FAIL:', '<strong><span style="background-color: #ff0000; color: #ffffff;">FAIL:</span></strong>') + '\n')
        elif "DEBUG" in line:
            OUT.write(line.replace('DEBUG:', '<strong><span style="color: #0000ff;">DEBUG:</span></strong>') + '\n')
        elif "WARNING" in line:
            OUT.write(line.replace('WARNING:', '<strong><span style="color: #F5A422;">WARNING:</span></strong>') + '\n')
        elif "START:" in line:
            f = '<span style="background-color: #FFC9FF; color: #731275;"><b>' + line + '</b></span>'
        elif "INFO:" in line:
            OUT.write(line.replace('INFO:', '<strong><span style="color: grey;">INFO:</span></strong>') + '\n')
        else:
            OUT.write(line + '\n')
    OUT.write("</pre")
    OUT.write('</body>')




path = open('output.html')
path_name = os.path.realpath(path.name)
url = 'file://' + path_name
webbrowser.open(url, new=2)
```

Comment: run it manually in console/terminal to see error messages.

Comment: so I open terminal and drag the .app in? It says permission denied

Comment: I was thinging about writing full path to file `.app` but I don't use `Mac`. So you have to change permition to run it.

Comment: When I drag it into terminal it puts the full path to the .app - I'm not sure how to change permissions for it, I'm logged into an admin account and get info shows read and write is enabled

Comment: it may need `executable` permission. At least it needs it on Linux/Unix and Mac currently is Unix-like system.

Comment: on Linux I can change it with right click to open context menu and there is `Proprerties` which show all permissions. OR in console running `chmod a+x full/path/to/file.app`

Comment: I tried chmod 755 which I think is the Mac equivalent and it hasn't resolved the issue. But more importantly, when I hand this .app to others, I don't want them to have to do this. Any idea what a better solution might be?

Comment: on Linux I can use `755` or `u+x` which is easier to remeber. First you have to recognize what is the problem and later you would have to find if it will be problem on other computers too. Maybe it is problem only on your computer and other people will not have to change anything. Or maybe it is problem only on admin account.

Comment: I don't use Mac so I can't help with this problem. You can only use Google with  text  `permission denied` and `Mac` and maybe `pyinstaller`. maybe someone already had this problem and he resolved it.